# WPF: How to create a UI library like "Telerik UI for WPF"?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, opengl, telerik

Due to some reasons I should create my own UI/GUI library for some apps. After a lot of searching I did not find suitable info for the project except this [link](https://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/overview.aspx).
This is the nearest thing to my idea that I've found yet.
Now I'd like to know how companies like Telerik could create these libraries, and how can I create some for myself? Do they use OpenGL or something like that to provide these libraries to the customers? What are the keywords that I should search for to learn the technology.
Thanks.

Comment: WPF contains its own graphic primitives based on DirectX.  Pick up a good book on WPF, and start reading.  I recommend *WPF 4 Unleashed.*

Comment: Thanks a lot @RobertHarvey, I'll give it a try. Does Telerik use this technique (DirectX) to implement the library?

Comment: WPF uses DirectX for rendering, so yeah I'd say that's a fair statement.

Comment: @MA: Telerik provides a set of custom controls. You don't need to implement something like OpenGL to be able to use these in a WPF application. Start with creating a class that inherits from `Control` or `FrameworkElement` and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical "UI library" like for example the one that Telerik provides for WPF is basically just a bunch of control classes that inherit from a built-in base class like for example `System.Windows.UIElement`, `FrameworkElement` or `Control`.

So a good staring point would be to create a class library based on any of the `WPF Control Library` template and add some classes and XAML templates to it.

You don't have to provide your own custom rendering engine to build a "UI library".